# jupyter integrate r -- > rmagic rpy2 - 2.8.3

Tags: python, r, jupyter

I have troubles integrating Jupyter with the latest rmagic of rpy2. 
Tutorials mention to load it like: `%load_ext rmagic` but this appears to be outdated:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions/rmagic.py:11: UserWarning: The rmagic extension in IPython has moved to `rpy2.ipython`, please see `rpy2` documentation.
  warnings.warn("The rmagic extension in IPython has moved to "
```

Trying to `execute %R x <- = runif(10)` or `%%R` magics results in `ERROR:root:Line magic function`%R`not found.`

But in Jupyter I can instantiate a R-notebook and execute commands just fine. So probably I am just calling the wrong magic?

Comment: Try `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`.

Comment: Indeed this works just fine. Thanks a lot. If you want to please write a solution.

Comment: Please report this to the authors of the tutorials. rmagic moved to rpy2 quite a while ago now.